# Transmission of Data

Tags: ipv6-transition

GOOD EVENING PEOPLE :D

1. What is the differentiate between **Basedband** & **Broadband** transmission ?

Answer (score 2):

Baseband refers to a transmission which uses all the bandwidth of a medium (encoded directly on the wire), while broadband means that a transmission only uses part of the bandwidth of a medium (multiple signals can be sent at the same time, modulated on a carrier wave).

An example of baseband is one of the ethernet variants with "BASE" in the name, such as 10BASE-T. Only one frame can be transmitted at a time on one link.

An example of broadband is cable TV/Internet. Multiple signals are traveling on one link simultaneously. Also, there was a version of ethernet using broadband called 10BROAD-36.

One caveat is that the government (FCC) has redefined broadband to mean any network signal over an arbitrary speed (I believe the threshold was originally 200 Kbps, but is now 25 Mbps).

Comment: can you explain with more details ?, please ...

Comment: What do you mean? Baseband directly places the bits on the wire with electrical signals, so it uses all the bandwidth, while broadband uses a carrier so that you can have multiple signals at the same time. What else could/should I say about it?

Comment: Hah. Just because the word "base" is in it doesn't make it baseband -- all ethernet is modulated on a carrier. RS232/485 serial would be baseband. Ethernet AUI/MII interfaces are baseband.

Comment: The IEEE call it baseband. For instance 10BASE5 and 10BASE2 run on a "_baseband coaxial system_", and 10BASE-T uses a "_baseband medium_".

Answer (score 1):

[Baseband](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseband) means any signal that isn't modulated to carrier, or multiplexed with other signals. It's the "base" signal.

[Broadband](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadband) is a wide bandwidth transmission, possibly modulated and multiplexed. It means pretty much exactly what the words *broad* and *band* mean. In the context of data communications it almost always means a large section of spectrum ("bandwidth") divided into discrete channels -- DSL, WiFi, DOCSIS, etc.